# Google Docs API with Python

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-docs-api

Using Google Document API, I'm trying to create new documents as well as supplying a list of all current documents within a specific folder in my Google Documents. I am starting out with python development, so I'm a little rough around the edges still.

Things I am trying to do:

1. Create a collection (or folder) with name [Folder Name] ONLY if that
   name does not exist yet
2. Create a document inside [Folder Name]
3. From only [Folder Name] get a list of documents along with links to
   the documents themselves

I believe I am using Google Docs API 3.0 and am using **gdata-2.0.16** helper for python.

Code so far:

```
    import gdata.docs.data
    import gdata.docs.client

    class SampleConfig(object):
        APP_NAME = 'GDataDocumentsListAPISample-v1.0'
        DEBUG = False

    client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient()
    client.ClientLogin('[email_address]','[password]',source=SampleConfig.APP_NAME )

    col = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='folder', title='Folder Name')
    col = client.CreateResource(col)

    doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='document', title='I did this')
    doc = client.CreateResource(doc, collection=col)
```

So now on to the questions: Where I am hopelessly stuck:

1. How do I check if [Folder name] exists?
2. How to retrieve the contents of ONLY [Folder Name]?
3. How do I get hold of absolute links to all documents I create in this folder?

I know I'm miles away from completion here, but any help or advice you could give would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[You can query for a folder or document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#searching_for_documents_and_files). Once you have the folder you can list its contents. Here is an example with the Python library:

```
# Create a query matching exactly a title, and include collections
q = gdata.docs.client.DocsQuery(
    title='EFD',
    title_exact='true',
    show_collections='true'
)

# Execute the query and get the first entry (if there are name clashes with
# other folders or files, you will have to handle this).
folder = client.GetResources(q=q).entry[0]

# Get the resources in the folder
contents = client.GetResources(uri=folder.content.src)

# Print out the title and the absolute link
for entry in contents.entry:
    print entry.title.text, entry.GetSelfLink().href
```

Output

```
My posted doc https://docs.google.com/...
subtestcoll2 https://docs.google.com/...
guestimates_1 https://docs.google.com/...
phase 2 delivery plan - draft https://docs.google.com/...
Meeting agenda June 09 https://docs.google.com/...
Phase 2 spec for Graeme 2 March 2009 https://docs.google.com/...
EFD Meeting 2nd June https://docs.google.com/...
```

Comment: Thanks for the details in your answer. Really appreciate it and I think I'm starting to get mine to work based on your example. However entry.GetSelfLink().href gives me a link in the format of: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%.... Which, when used in a browser, get's me "Invalid request URI"